# artifactory upgrade from 7.19.4 to 7.77.5

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling, upgrade, artifactory

[ steps ]

- stop artifactory
- stop mysql
- Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.07
- Upgrade mysql-server to 5.7
- Downloaded 7.75.5.tar.gz file put it into /opt/jfrog/artifactory
- untared 7.77.5.tar.gz
- removed /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app
- cp -r /opt/jfrog/artifactory/7.77.5/app/* /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app
- started up mysql-server
- started artifactory.

Looking at console.log got to this db error:

"Could not initialize database: org.flyawaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Detected failed migration to version 7.44 (Add Access Permission v2 ref"

Any ideas on what I can check on, do from here?

Thanks!

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)? Please edit your question to include the text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get this working:

### Make sure to use the same version of artifactory

Follow: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/method-1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we have at least 3 major issues here. There may be more...

1. Please see the Release note [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/artifactory-7.77.3-self-hosted).

Operating Systems - End of Support
As part of JFrog commitment to maintain the security and reliability of the JFrog Platform, Artifactory will officially run with Node.js 20.x on all installation types from Artifactory 7.77.3.

Node.js 20.x provided with Linux Archive/Debian/RPM installations (non-containerized distributions) is not supported on the following operating systems.

Ubuntu 18.04 (has reached End of Standard Support on May 31, 2023).

**You are using Ubuntu 16.07 which is not supported...**

Currently Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 are supported. Full list of supported OS [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-system-requirements-and-platform-support)

2. There is a known issue with 7.77.x and some MYSQL installations during the PermissionsV2DataMigration due to need for super user permissions by default.
   This can be resolved by using 7.77.7 release (coming soon) or with a workaround. But note, this is not your current issue!
3. Your specific error seems to actually be occurring on an earlier DB migration but I am not 100% sure of the root cause without more logs then what you have shared.

But #1 is an insurmountable issue that must be dealt with first.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.   Currently, I have 14.04 so I am trying to get upgraded to a supported platform/version.    With the above, I attempted to upgrade to 16.04 to get MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7, which I believe fixed one issue during the db upgrade with a table creation.   What I'm thinking of doing now is to just do rsync on the filestore and do a System Export / Import to a new host.   Problem is that I seem to be running into import issues as described here on how to do this.

Comment: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/method-1   :       Is this a better way to go for getting current?  Is there something different I should be doing?           Errors seem to be related to matching up files in the filestore to what is being done in the system import.   Perhaps I'am missing a step.